# how to show logged in owner owned records in salesforce

Tags: sharing

I need to show only the records which has been created by loggedin user. Iam not thinking to use apex.Need Suggestion.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to display in a List View or Report?

Comment: in both @sfdcFanBoy

Comment: @developersfdc check the answer that I have provided.

Comment: @DhananjayPatil cant i use any out of box functionality?! i mean sharing setting?!

Comment: @developersfdc for List View you can see My List View which is salesforce out of the box. e.g. If you are on Account object then you can see 'My Account' list view that display only those records created by you.But in report you need to apply filter for different users.So I recommend to try the workaround that I have provided.You can check this link for more details https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214161&type=1

Comment: It would be nice to get votes to this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrlpAAC that is pretty much the same thing :D

Answer (score 1):

You need set the **Organization wide default** setting of the object to **"Private"**

Go to Setup --> Sharing Settings --> Edit.  Select Private from the dropdown for the respective object.

[image]

Private implies that Only the record owner, and users above that role in the hierarchy, can view, edit, and report on those records.

Comment: can i hide based on Profile like "cc" profile of the loggedin user ==CC then only it should display.

Comment: So combination of Loggedin User and his profile isCC

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula checkbox field ($User.Id = [CreatedBy, Owner.Id, etc]) and then filter the report to only pick up records where this field = true.

Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a Formula(Text) Field.Lets say I'm creatng Formula Field **Current User**.

```
IF( $User.Id = CreatedBy.Id,"Yes", "No" )
```

Make the Visibility of field to all profile and hide it from page layout.

Create a list view on the object where you want to display the record.Create a new view and set the filter criteria for **Current User** to True.

This will filter and display all records where Current User name equals Logged in user.

Check the link for more details:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214161&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220171&type=1

let me know if it helps.

Comment: this will work for the new entries,for old entries i have to write bacth job for the existing records to update the existing records.

Comment: No it will work for old entries too. You are using formula field here so formula field calculates every times.Just create the formula and let me know.

Comment: @Dhananjay.I tried,it is not showing the records as expected.creating a formula field will not update the field value.

Comment: Your formula sets the value to true only if you as loggin user create a record.What is that criteria that you've set in list view?

Comment: @developersfdc check the link that I have mentioned then you will decide if you want to use it or not.